Downloading function from Azure Function Portal
I have a couple of Powershell functions on my Azure Function app, that were created directly in the Portal, and I would like to download them locally to my computer. I saw that there is an option to manually download a zip file containing everything, but I tried to do it and it has been going on for 2 hours now, even though I only have a couple of Functions. Is there a quicker way to do that, perhaps using Azure CLI? I didn't see anything like that in Microsoft's documentation, but maybe there is a way that I haven't discovered yet?

Azure function can be download from portal in two ways. Refer MSDOC.
From Portal UI:

In Overview of the function app, select Download App Content=>choose Site content or Content and Visual Studio project=>Download.




This downloads the function as zip to local.

Using REST APIs:

Browse the URL by updating the functionappname.

https://<function_appname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/wwwroot/

This downloads the function content as zip to local.

Contents of the extracted zip folder:

